# Simplification of complex expressions

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

The other day I wanted to simplify a following expression:

```
a Conjugate[a]//FullSimplify
```

Great! The answer we receive is Abs[a]^2.
Now I tried something like this:

```
a b Conjugate[a]//FullSimplify (*a Conjugate[a] b will return the same output*)
```

Unfortunatelly it wasn't simplified. LeafCount prefers the unsimplified expression over Abs[a]^2 b. ComplexityFunction should be able to fix this:
[ComplexityFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComplexityFunction.html)

I used the function presented in the link above:

```
f[e_] := StringLength[ToString[InputForm[e]]]
FullSimplify[a Conjugate[a] b, ComplexityFunction -> f]
```

And I still get the unwanted form.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just learned this from my question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19855/simplify-sinx-x-to-sincx) at StackExchange. You can do it like this:

```
f[expr_]:=expr/.x_*Conjugate[x_]:>Abs[x]^2
Simplify[a Conjugate[a] b,TransformationFunctions->{Automatic,f},ComplexityFunction->(StringLength[ToString[InputForm[#]]]&)]
```

it will give `b Abs[a]^2`.